# Wordpress Gutenberg e2e testing - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:8889

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to get a simple set of e2e tests running on a Gutenberg block. It's from an existing Git repo to demonstrate e2e testing. I haven't made any alterations, but the author hasn't replied so I'm trying myself to get it working.

Below is a single test (I have commented out the others for now until I can get one passing):

```
import {
    createNewPost,
    enablePageDialogAccept,
    getEditedPostContent,
    insertBlock,
} from '@wordpress/e2e-test-utils';

describe( 'Wrapper block', () => {
    beforeAll( async () => {
        await enablePageDialogAccept();
    } );
    beforeEach( async () => {
        await createNewPost();
    } );

    it( 'Wrapper block should be available', async () => {
        await insertBlock( 'Wrapper Block' );

        // Check if block was inserted
        expect( await page.$( '[data-type="e2e-tests-example/wrapper-block"]' ) ).not.toBeNull();

        expect( await getEditedPostContent() ).toMatchSnapshot();
    } );
} );
```

Below is my package.json with versions and script commands:

```
{
  "name": "e2e-tests-example",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test:e2e": "wp-scripts test-e2e"
  },
  "wp-env": {
    "plugin-dir": "e2e-tests-example",
    "plugin-name": "E2E Tests Example",
    "docker-template": "./docker-compose.override.yml",
    "welcome-logo": [
      "E2E Tests Example"
    ],
    "welcome-build-command": "npm run dev"
  }
}
```

When I try to run the e2e tests, it seems that the test environment isn't available so just errors:

```
PS C:\...\e2e-tests-example-wp-plugin> npm run test:e2e

> e2e-tests-example@1.0.0 test:e2e C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis-wp\wp-content\plugins\e2e-tests-example-wp-plugin
> wp-scripts test-e2e

 FAIL  e2e-tests/wrapper-block.spec.js (7.233s)
  ● Wrapper block › Wrapper block should be available

    net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:8889/wp-admin/post-new.php

      at navigate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:120:37)
        -- ASYNC --
      at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
      at Page.goto (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:675:49)
      at Page.goto (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
      at _callee$ (node_modules/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/build/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/src/visit-admin-page.js:20:13)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
        -- ASYNC --
      at Page.goto (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
      at _callee$ (node_modules/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/build/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/src/visit-admin-page.js:20:13)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:21:12

  ● Wrapper block › Wrapper block should be available

    No node found for selector: .edit-post-header [aria-label="Add block"]

      at assert (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:283:11)
      at DOMWorld.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:366:5)
        -- ASYNC --
      at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
      at Page.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1067:29)
      at _callee$ (node_modules/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/build/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils/src/open-global-block-inserter.js:5:13)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7

 › 3 snapshots obsolete.
   • Wrapper block Alignment should be set 1
   • Wrapper block Background color should be applied 1
   • Wrapper block Margin bottom should be applied 1
 FAIL  e2e-tests/wrapper-block-filters.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:242:24
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:131:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:151:9)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:156:7
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:148:12
      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:271:25)

Snapshot Summary
 › 3 snapshots obsolete from 1 test suite. To remove them all, re-run jest with `-u`.
   ↳ e2e-tests/wrapper-block.spec.js
       • Wrapper block Alignment should be set 1
       • Wrapper block Background color should be applied 1
       • Wrapper block Margin bottom should be applied 1
Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   3 obsolete, 0 total
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! e2e-tests-example@1.0.0 test:e2e: `wp-scripts test-e2e`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e-tests-example@1.0.0 test:e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-11T11_17_03_665Z-debug.log
```

If I've missed any other files that I need to include, let me know. The repo I'm working from can be found here (with all the files) - https://github.com/liip/e2e-tests-example-wp-plugin

I notice there is a docker-compose.override.yml files but no instruction to run any docker containers manually, and no docker-compose.yml files. I'm not finding a ton of resources on e2e testing with gutenberg, just thought it would be nice to work from a working project and learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but in my case it was happening because there was a port conflict between MAMP and Puppeteer.
To avoid it I was using a custom port for the Docker instance, but Puppeteer was still accessing the  default  8889 port.

Tu run the Docker instance on   a  custom port I used the .wp-env.js file and added to it the port parameter:

```
{
    "core": "WordPress/WordPress",
    "plugins": ["."],
    "port": 3338
}
```

Then you start the Docker instance like:

```
npm run wp-env start
```

And to run the test on the custom port you  can run:

```
npm run test:e2e -- --wordpress-base-url=http://localhost:3338/
```

The command above can run the tests against a non Docker environment or in our case on a custom port.